# if new app isn't 64-bit. Will apple reject it?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

**if new app isn't 64-bit. will apple reject it.**

Hello All.

I have created a new app. its only support 32bit. If it is not support 64 bit. will apple reject it.?

Answer (score 1):

Its a recommendation to be 64bit compatible, but at the current time it is not required. However your app must be built with Xcode 5 and optimized for iOS 7. [Link to Apple Announcement](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a#top)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I conclude that its only a recommendation and current time its not required.